# Unable to figure out what the type of a function is

Tags: haskell

I have this function:

```
import Data.Aeson
import Network.HTTP.Conduit

getJSON url = eitherDecode <$> simpleHttp url
```

which is called as:

```
maybeJson <- getJSON "https://abc.com" :: IO (Either String Value)
```

However, I can't figure out what the type of getJSON is. I've been trying these:

```
getJSON :: FromJSON a => String ->  Either String a --1
getJSON :: String ->  Either String Value --2
```

plus some other ones but failed. What is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main thing you're missing in your attempts so far is the `IO` type. One correct type given your current usage is

```
getJSON :: String -> IO (Either String Value)
```

You can see that the `IO` type must be needed given your `maybeJSON` line - that makes it clear that `getJSON <something>` returns `IO (Either String Value)`.

In fact the exact type is more general:

```
getJSON :: (FromJSON a, MonadIO m, Functor m) => String -> m (Either String a)
```

To go into more detail on how to derive the correct type, we need to look carefully at the types of [`simpleHttp`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.2.3/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v%3asimpleHttp) and [`eitherDecode`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.6.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v%3aeitherDecode):

```
eitherDecode :: FromJSON a => ByteString -> Either String a
simpleHttp :: MonadIO m => String -> m ByteString
```

They're also being combined with `(<$>)` from [`Control.Applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html):

```
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Putting it all together gives the type above - the `f` for `(<$>)` and the `m` for `simpleHttp` must be the same, and the input type is the `String` being fed into `simpleHttp`, and the result type is the result type of `eitherDecode`, lifted into `m` by the `(<$>)` operation.

You can also just ask GHC to tell you the answer. Either load your module up in ghci and use `:t getJSON`, or leave out the type signature, compile with `-Wall` and look at the warning about the missing type signature for `getJSON`.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you don't have to explicitly declare a type for your functions in Haskell. The compiler will deduce them for you. In fact, you can use the `:type` command (or just `:t` for short) in `ghci` to let the compiler tell you the type of a function after you load the source file.

Comment: of course, I don't have to. But it's a good habit to declare the type of a function before using it.

Comment: @Grienders Yes, but "first write the function without a type signature, then ask the compiler what its type is, then add the signature" is a perfectly fine way to do this.